# Binding to a custom property of a custom control property isn't working

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I am working on a custom control. I want it to support data-binding, so it is as easy to maintain as the built-in controls are.

Here is what I got so far:

- the window Window.xaml code that contains my control:

  ```
  <custom:Matrix x:Name="customMatrix" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Title="{Binding Title}"/>
  ```
- ... and its Window.xaml.cs code-behind (just a fragment of a viewmodel)

  ```
  public ViewModel VM { get; private set; }

  private ProblemManager()
  {
      VM = new ViewModel();

      InitializeComponent();

      DataContext = VM;
      VM.Title = "a title";
  }

  public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public ViewModel()
      {
          ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<List<int>>();
      }
      public ObservableCollection<List<int>> ItemsList { get; set; }

      protected string title;
      public string Title
      {
          get { return title; }
          set
          {
              if (title != value)
              {
                  title = value;
                  NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
              }
          }
      }

      protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- my control Matrix.xaml

  ```
  // ...
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
  // ...
  ```
- and the control's Matrix.xaml.cs code-behind

  ```
  public partial class Matrix : UserControl
  {
      public Matrix()
      {
          InitializeComponent();

          DataContext = this;
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(Matrix), new PropertyMetadata("", TitleChanged));
      public string Title
      {
          get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
          set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
      }
      private void TitleChanged(string title)
      {
          Title = title;
      }
      private static void TitleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          ((Matrix)d).TitleChanged((string)e.NewValue);
      }
  }
  ```

And the thing is that if not binding in my window xaml to the `Matrix.Title` property i.e. giving that value statically in xaml like `Title="some title"` the binding inside my control code works (I can even do `customMatrix.Title += "1";` in my window and it works). However, when binding to the `Matrix.Title` property (like I did in the code provided), it does not work and I got a blank title in my view. Just to state it clearly, binding to default controls in the window works.

*How to make the* `Matrix.Title` *property bindable?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextBlock binding on your Matrix control is wrong.

You've set up a dependency property and then the code in your Window.xaml is binding that property to Title in your Window class. That part is all fine, although you don't need the TitleChanged function (the binding gets done automatically so you don't need to do it manually yourself). The problem is that the TextBlock.Text property in your UserControl is declared like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
```

So it's trying to bind to the UserControl's current DataContext, and if you haven't set that (which you apparently haven't) then it inherits it from MainWindow which may or may not be what you want it to be. To fix this you need to bind the TextBlock to the *UserControl's* property, not the DataContext property, and you do that with FindAncester:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type custom:Matrix}}, Path=Title}" />
```

UPDATED: Another way to do this is to give the UserControl in your Matrix.xaml file a name and bind to it with ElementName:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourProjectNameHere.Matrix"
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Wpftest2"
         ... more namespaces here
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
         Name="thisControl">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="theTextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=thisControl, Path=Title}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Isn't specifying the DataContext of my control done in the `Matrix` constructor by `DataContext = this;`?

Comment: Doh! I didn't even see that :) But yeah, that's your problem right there, you can't just change the DataContext to point to whatever you want to because it gets changed out from under you when placed on the main window. Get rid of the TitleChanged function, delete that line that assigns the Data Context in your user control and use use a FindAncestor binding and that will fix your problem.

Comment: Are you saying that the `DataContext = this;` assignment has no effect when I use the control somewhere else? Anyway, I am trying to do what you told me to do. Placing this binding declaration in Matrix.xaml gives me an error that the `custom` isn't defined. Indeed that isn't, because I use `custom` as my xaml namespace in Window.xaml. I also tried to have `x:Type Matrix` with no luck. What is the thing I am missing now?

Comment: I've just done some testing of this and it turns out I was wrong, the binding gets done before you manually set DataContext to 'this'. In any case, it's still incorrect because the data context needs to be correctly set to the ViewModel in order for the binding to work on the MainWindow:

<custom:Matrix x:Name="customMatrix" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Title="{Binding Title}" />

So as I was saying you need to get rid of the 'DataContext = this' statement and bind to the UserControl using RelativeSource. The error you are getting is because you haven'y included a namespace for "custom".

Comment: It must be on your MainWindow, otherwise you'd be getting the error there are well (I'm assuming your dragged your control onto that window and it was generated automatically. Look in your main window xaml for something like this and add it to your Matrix xaml as well:

xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:YourProjectName"

If you're still having trouble then I've updated my answer with another way of achieving this.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Well, now I am confused. Why does assigning `DataContext` to `this` in control's code-behind isn't supposed to work while in my Window.xaml it works well? I mean that as you can see, in my Window.xaml.cs (which is actually named `ProblemManager`) I assign an instance of `ViewModel` class to `ProblemManager`'s `DataContext`. Is it in any way different when it comes to custom controls?

Comment: This actually seem to work. I am wondering how that is. I mean I placed a breakpoint within `Matrix.Title` setter and it never gets hit. Still the UI and the value are both updated. Is it because of the `DependencyProperty` that changes the value with `SetValue` and not because the `Title` property itself?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The property getters/setters are there just for convenience, the WPF binding mechanism still works without them. Unfortunately the designers of WPF weren't able to shoe-horn data-binding in with the existing language property features so they basically had to replace it altogether with Dependency Properties. The down-side is that you can't put handler code in setters anymore because they won't always be called, you must instead add callbacks to the dependency property itself.

Comment: What confuses me is that why is it necessary to go your way and name my control just to bind a property of that control, all inside the control, while the "inner" control binding worked with `DataContext` set to `this` (control) and I could see that working by manually changing the `Matrix.Title` property outside (in my Window.xaml.cs). Did anyway the "outer" binding (by that I mean the `<custom:Matrix x:Name="customMatrix" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Title="{Binding Title}"/>` binding in my Window.xaml) call anything of the `Matrix.TitleProperty` of type `DependencyProperty`?

Comment: I'll try and explain it better...in your ProblemManager you start by creating a ViewModel but you don't do anything with it yet. Then you called InitializeComponent, which created your Matrix control. Your Matrix control called InitializeComponent which set it's DataContext to null automatically, but then you overrode it to point to itself. The text control in Matrix is using the DataContext, so it is binding to Matrix.Title. Now back in your ProblemManager you set the DataContext to VM, but you're doing it to the ProblemManager, your Matrix control DataContext has already been changed.

Comment: And then again in ProblemManager you try to do a "VM.Title = 'a title'". you're changing the ProblemManager's DataContext object i.e. the instance of ViewModel, but the Matrix control and it's textbox arent pointing to this object anymore. I think the key source of confusion here is that when your Matrix control is initially created it's DataContext is set to null. When a controls DataContext is null it uses it's parent's DataContext instead. If  you then go ahead and change that child controls DataContext you're not changing the parent's as well, the child is just no longer doing the default.

Comment: I actually expected both binding Window to its `ViewModel` and Matrix to itself to be separated. That is the `Matrix.Title` being bound to its `<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>` independently and then with `<custom:Matrix x:Name="customMatrix" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Title="{Binding Title}"/>` from `ProblemManager` Window binding `ProblemManager.VM.Title` to the Matrix property `Matrix.Title`. And since the `Matrix` binding worked, the binding of `Title`s must have not.

Comment: If I got it right, when I assign `Matrix.DataContext` to itself anyway, both `DataContext`s should be separated and work with something close to my approach, is that right or am I just going a completely wrong path?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In the original code you posted for this question change the line [ VM.Title = "a title"; ] to [this.customMatrix.Title = "a title"; ] and you'll see it works as you intend because the Matrix user control and it's TextBlock child are now both using Matrix as their new DataContext. You'll also notice that VM.Title does not change when you do this.